# Is it possible to switch from proxmox 2.2 to 4.4 and use the same containers?

Tags: upgrade, proxmox

I've got a very old internal server where I'm changing drives and was thinking it would be useful to upgrade proxmox from 2.2 to current 4.4.
Is it possible to just install 4.4 and reuse the same images as I used with 2.2? How can I do that?

Thanks
Krystian

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably looking for, since 4.4 uses LXC (Linux Containers) instead of OpenVZ containers, is this guide:

https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Convert_OpenVZ_to_LXC

Comment: Sounds great, how about a switch from 2.2 to 3.x? It still uses OpenVZ, so hopefully I don't have to do anything to my images?

Comment: Is there anything specific you want to be upgrading for, feature wise? Otherwise, I'd check how long each major version is going to be supported/supplied with security fixes, and decide based upon that. 

Upgrading to an intermediate version then realizing that support for it is expiring in a few weeks/months and you'll have to upgrade again to keep the security fixes coming in is the kind of extra work that can be avoided, even if the version gap to the current version is bigger and migration tougher.

This is generally speaking, though.